# Merge multiple threads into one in Python

Tags: python, multithreading, fractals

I wrote a very basic, poorly optimized fractal generator.
However, it has one major flaw: the iterating function diverges() that is used to verify whether a complex number is in the Mandelbrot set or not cannot use multiple threads, making the generation of images larger than 2000*2000 pixels very slow. How could I "merge" several threads to execute the program faster? Here is the code:
`

```
import numpy
from random import choice
import matplotlib.pyplot as plot

z = complex(0, 0)
c = complex(0, 0)
global n
n = int(input("RESOLUTION? "))
iterations = int(input("ITERATIONS? "))


def squarer(z, c):
    if z == 0:
        return 0
    else:
        return z * z + c


def getcmap():
    cmap_list = (
    'Accent', 'Accent_r', 'Blues', 'Blues_r', 'BrBG', 'BrBG_r', 'BuGn', 'BuGn_r', 'BuPu', 'BuPu_r', 'CMRmap',
    'CMRmap_r', 'Dark2', 'Dark2_r', 'GnBu', 'GnBu_r', 'Greens', 'Greens_r', 'Greys', 'Greys_r', 'OrRd', 'OrRd_r',
    'Oranges', 'Oranges_r', 'PRGn', 'PRGn_r', 'Paired', 'Paired_r', 'Pastel1', 'Pastel1_r', 'Pastel2', 'Pastel2_r',
    'PiYG', 'PiYG_r', 'PuBu', 'PuBuGn', 'PuBuGn_r', 'PuBu_r', 'PuOr', 'PuOr_r', 'PuRd', 'PuRd_r', 'Purples',
    'Purples_r', 'RdBu', 'RdBu_r', 'RdGy', 'RdGy_r', 'RdPu', 'RdPu_r', 'RdYlBu', 'RdYlBu_r', 'RdYlGn', 'RdYlGn_r',
    'Reds', 'Reds_r', 'Set1', 'Set1_r', 'Set2', 'Set2_r', 'Set3', 'Set3_r', 'Spectral', 'Spectral_r', 'Wistia',
    'Wistia_r', 'YlGn', 'YlGnBu', 'YlGnBu_r', 'YlGn_r', 'YlOrBr', 'YlOrBr_r', 'YlOrRd', 'YlOrRd_r', 'afmhot',
    'afmhot_r', 'autumn', 'autumn_r', 'binary', 'binary_r', 'bone', 'bone_r', 'brg', 'brg_r', 'bwr', 'bwr_r',
    'cividis', 'cividis_r', 'cool', 'cool_r', 'coolwarm', 'coolwarm_r', 'copper', 'copper_r', 'cubehelix',
    'cubehelix_r', 'flag', 'flag_r', 'gist_earth', 'gist_earth_r', 'gist_gray', 'gist_gray_r', 'gist_heat',
    'gist_heat_r', 'gist_ncar', 'gist_ncar_r', 'gist_rainbow', 'gist_rainbow_r', 'gist_stern', 'gist_stern_r',
    'gist_yarg', 'gist_yarg_r', 'gnuplot', 'gnuplot2', 'gnuplot2_r', 'gnuplot_r', 'gray', 'gray_r', 'hot', 'hot_r',
    'hsv', 'hsv_r', 'inferno', 'inferno_r', 'jet', 'jet_r', 'magma', 'magma_r', 'nipy_spectral', 'nipy_spectral_r',
    'ocean', 'ocean_r', 'pink', 'pink_r', 'plasma', 'plasma_r', 'prism', 'prism_r', 'rainbow', 'rainbow_r',
    'seismic', 'seismic_r', 'spring', 'spring_r', 'summer', 'summer_r', 'tab10', 'tab10_r', 'tab20', 'tab20_r',
    'tab20b', 'tab20b_r', 'tab20c', 'tab20c_r', 'terrain', 'terrain_r', 'turbo', 'turbo_r', 'twilight', 'twilight_r',
    'twilight_shifted', 'twilight_shifted_r', 'viridis', 'viridis_r', 'winter', 'winter_r')
    return choice(cmap_list)


def diverges(c, iterations, threshold=4):
    i = 0
    z = c
    while i < iterations and (z * z.conjugate()).real < threshold:
        z = squarer(z, c)
        i += 1
    return i


def plotter(n, iterations):
    mx = 2.48 / (float(n) - 1)
    my = 2.26 / (float(n) - 1)
    mapper = lambda x, y: (mx * x - 2, my * y - 1.13)
    img = numpy.full((n, n), 255)

    for x in range(n):
        for y in range(n):
            it = diverges(complex(*mapper(x, y)), iterations, threshold=4)
            img[y][x] = 255 - float(it)
    return img


img = plotter(n, iterations=iterations)
plot.imshow(img, cmap=getcmap())
plot.axis("off")
plot.show()
```

`
I tried using the threading module to execute every function on a different thread. The results were a very slight improvement, definitely not worth the hassle. Only one function takes a substantial amount. Of course this is not the finished project, but having a fast renderer is crucial. The resolution has to be given as a single value (p.ex. 400 for 400*400 pixels)

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Threads are unlikely to improve performance.

Comment: You can't "merge" multiple threads to execute serial code faster. That's like trying to merge 9 women to make a baby in 1 month.

Comment: Remember that only one thread at a time can be executing Python code.  If you can defer more of the processing to numpy, that will help, but if you are reading and writing a single array, it may be the algorithm isn't amenable to parallelization.

Comment: Have a look at [numba](https://numba.pydata.org/). It makes python code fast.

Comment: OK thank you! I'll search Numba up and try to use it for my script.

Comment: After a few tweaks to not include any unsupported functions, my code runs 10x faster with caching on! Thank you so much!